# Where are API keys stored in cPanel file manager?

Tags: cpanel, file-manager

I recently bought a script. Where would I go to change an API key in file manager? Is there a specific area I am supposed to navigate to for finding API keys?

I'm sorry that I feel I'm being unclear but I don't know how to explain better. If I can just get a general answer I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: What script did you buy?  What is it for?    Different scripts have different ways of managing their API keys.   If you could tell us which script it is or at least which company you bought it from, it would let us tell you mare about where it looks for its API keys.

Answer (score 1):

In cpanel go to the `security` section and you should find `Manage API tokens` but this is marked as "Warning: The API Tokens feature is experimental."

There is more information at cPanel API Management documentation https://api.docs.cpanel.net/openapi/cpanel/tag/API-Token-Management/